# AngularJS - Infinte Loop over a finite array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of anything from 10-500 records appearing on screen as a graphical array using standard NG-REPEAT, visualisation is a row of photographs

What I would like to achieve, but cant quite get my head around if its even possible is this...

A 'window' on screen that will only show 10 records - Done
You can scroll left or right through the entire list - Done

HOWEVER

What i would LIKE to achieve is that when the end of the list is reached, the list starts again from the beginning but in an infinite style loop. Both directions

I have never done anything like this and not quite sure how I would achieve this of my ng-repeat (item in ListofItems)

So I assume that the best solution is

when the user gets 40 records through 100 records, i push() the first 20 records from my $scope.ListofItems to the end of the array, and remove the equivalent first 20 records from the front.. this keeps a constant list of 100 records, no massive memory usage.. i can even do this on an individual record basis.. remove one record from end or beginning and add at the beginning or end of the list.

The user experience is an infinite scroll, but I suspect the browser experience could be slow and stuttering due to the processing going on

Push(), Pull(), Tracking and indexing would play a part but any suggestions would be appreciated whether this is even technically possible

EDIT : After some research. maybe

```
$scope.ListofItems.push($scope.ListofItems.shift());
```

could be a solution to move beginning to end, but not sure how to trigger this or go the other way (pull?)

EDIT2 : Just did a manually called function for the above and it shifts front item to end of list, though i would have no clue how to read the screen position to know when to fire the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going the other way around could be

```
$scope.ListofItems.unshift($scope.ListofItems.pop());
```

As a side note, I think it's important to keep in mind for large arrays that `shift()` and `unshift()` naturally cause a full reindexing and have a time complexity of O(n) where n is the length of the array, as opposed to `push()` and `pop()` which have a time complexity of O(1)

Comment: Ah, unshift.. thats why my pop did nothing. I now have the mechanisms for going both ways should I need to move forwards with this. Thanks